# Prescribing Gaussian curvature

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature

I am interested in what possible (local) restrictions there are for Gaussian curvature in dimension 2. More precisely, given a function $f: D^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, is there a metric on $D^2$ with Gaussian curvature $f$?

An even more local version is the following: given a germ of a function $f$ around the origin in $D^2$, is there a germ of a metric with Gauss curvature f? That is, given $f: D^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, is there an open subset $U$ around the origin and a metric on $U$ with Gaussian curvature $f|_U$?

Comment: @MoisheCohen: I believe the answer to this local question is known in the real-analytic category.  (I'm also not sure how Gauss-Bonnet would come into play here, since the question is local.)

Comment: @JesseMadnick: Yes of course, but I was commenting on the "more precise" question, which is not local.

Comment: @JesseMadnick I edited my question and added a version of the question that is indeed local. You said it is known in this case? what is the reference?

Comment: You might consider looking into the results of Jerry Kazdan and Frank Warner:  https://www.amazon.com/Prescribing-Curvature-Riemannian-Conference-Mathematics/dp/0821807072

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The local question is settled by DeTurck in 1980, see his announcement 
"[The equation of prescribed Ricci curvature](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1980-03-01/S0273-0979-1980-14800-4/S0273-0979-1980-14800-4.pdf)", Proposition 4.1.

A proof appeared in his paper "Metrics with prescribed Ricci curvature",  Seminar on Differential Geometry, pp. 525–537, Ann. of Math. Stud., 102, Princeton Univ. Press, Princeton, N.J., 1982.

The problem is open when you want to construct a metric in the given conformal class. However, if your curvature function is real-analytic, then local existence (in the given conformal class) follows from Cauch-Kovalevskaya theorem.